# Estimating parameters of a linear equation using MCMC: Why so much variability in the c parameter?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

I'm currently trying to understand parameter estimation using MCMC via estimating the two parameters of a linear equation (`m` and `c`). My code works and produces histograms representing a probability distribution for the `m` parameter but not for the `c` parameter. My questions is: why? Is it because the `c` parameter represents a structural non-identifiability(to use ODE terminology)? or is there something else wrong with my code?

**Some example output**

[image: probability distribution for <code>m</code> parameter]

[image: probability distribution for <code>c</code> parameter]

[image: Model being fit (red=actual model, green=estiamted)]

My code: Three matlab scripts, one objective function, one model function and one run script.

**The objective function**

```
function chi2 = SSR(sim,exp,sigma)
%%
% sim= simulated data
% exp= experimental data
% sigma = standard deviation

chi2 =sum(  (  ([sim]-[exp])./ ( 2*sigma^2) ).^2);
```

**The model function**

```
function y=mx_plus_c(m,x,c)

dim=size(x);
if dim(1)==1,
    if dim(2)==1,
        y=m*[x]+c;
else
    y=m*[x]+c;
    end
end
```

**The run code:**

```
%% Simulate some data from a linear equation
interval=1:100;
y=mx_plus_c((38),interval,(4));
% y=log10(y);
%% Attempt at estimating the parameters using MCMC methodology
n=1e5; %iterations

%create a storage vector
vec=zeros(n,6);
% Define starting point for both estimated parameters
m=(50);
c=(50);

%U~(1,100) for both parameters
%matlab way of generating samples from uniform
% r = a + (b-a).*rand(N,1)
a1=1;
b1=100;
a2=1;
b2=100;
chi2_current=SSR( mx_plus_c(  m,interval,c) , y, 0.0001);
count=0;
for i=1:n,
    m_prop   =    ( (a1+(b1-a1).*rand(1,1)   )  );
    c_prop   =    ( (a2+(b2-a2).*rand(1,1)   )  );

    chi2_prop=SSR( mx_plus_c(  m_prop,interval,c_prop) , y, 0.0001);
    aprop=min(1,chi2_current/chi2_prop);
    vec(i,4)=aprop;
%     ratio=exp((-chi2_prop+chi2_current)  /  2*0.001^2);
% end

    random_value=rand;
    vec(i,5)=random_value;
    if random_value< aprop,
        count=count+1;
        m=m_prop;
        c=c_prop;
        chi2_current=chi2_prop;

        vec(i,1)=m;
        vec(i,2)=c;
        vec(i,3)=chi2_current;

        a1=m_prop-2;
        a2=c_prop-2;

        b1=m_prop+2;
        b2=c_prop+2;
    end
    vec(i,6)=count/(n)*100;

%     if vec(i,3)-vec(i-50,3)==0,

end
%     
T=table(vec(:,1),vec(:,2),vec(:,3),vec(:,4),vec(:,5),vec(:,4)-vec(:,5),vec(:,6), ... 
    'VariableNames',{'m','c','chi2','aprop','random','aprop_minus_random','acc_rate'});
T=T(n*0.1:end,:);
%% 

figure(1)
% normalized_m=T.m(T.m~=0)/max(T.m);
histogram(T.m(T.m~=0),100,'Normalization','probability');
d=fitdist(T.m(T.m~=0),'normal');
hold on
plot(normpdf(min(T.m):max(T.m),d.mu,d.sigma))
hold off
% figure
% histfit(T.m(T.m~=0),100,'Normalization','probability');
t1=['m,mu=' num2str(d.mu) ' sigma=' num2str(d.sigma) ]
title(t1)
xlabel('parameter_value')
ylabel('freq')


figure(2)
% normalized_m=T.m(T.m~=0)/max(T.m);
histogram(T.c(T.c~=0),100,'Normalization','probability');
d2=fitdist(T.c(T.c~=0),'normal');
hold on
plot(normpdf(min(T.c):max(T.c),d2.mu,d2.sigma))
hold off

t2=['c,mu=' num2str(d2.mu) ' sigma=' num2str(d2.sigma)]
title(t2 )
xlabel('parameter_value')
ylabel('freq')
% xlim([4.5 5.5])

y_prime=mx_plus_c((d.mu),interval,(d2.mu));
figure(3)
plot(interval,y_prime,'color','red')
hold on
plot(interval,y,'color','green')
title('y_fit')
```

Comment: Although I am not familiar with Matlab (and cannot run the code), I find surprising that you divide by sigma^2 rather than sigma, since this is not scale invariant.

Comment: To be honest I don't know any better - but I'll chnge it and see what the results show...but I don't think it will make much of a difference in terms of MCMC output? sigma and sigma^2 are both constants after all.

Comment: I am also wondering if the code `aprop=min(1,chi2_current/chi2_prop)` makes sense as `chi2_current/chi2_prop`seems to miss an exponential, as in `exp(chi2_current-chi2_prop)`.

Comment: Its interesting you should say that since I tried an alternative (`exp((-chi2_prop+chi2_current)  /  2*0.001^2)`) because I read it on a post somewhere. But the literature I read said to use the aprop=min(1,chi2_current/chi2_prop)` so I stuck with it.

Comment: This shows you should (a) explain the problem in statistical terms through a genuine probabilistic model and (b) read the basics of Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. This forum is not intended for debugging raw code.